# Reading chat message using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am using regex in Java to read contents of messages from a text file, where each conversation is of the format:

02/05/16, 12:05 AM - ‪+91 00580 00000: Hello

02/05/16, 12:06 AM - ‪Ross Clark‬: Hello there!

I have formed the following pattern:
`\d\d/\d\d/\d\d,\s\d{1,2}:\d\d(\s\w\w)?\s-\s((\w+\s?\w+)|(\+\d{2}\s\d{5}\s\d{5})): ((.*)(\n)*(.*))+`

The problem is that the output shows the chats which have the name of the sender, for example in the above chat sample, message sent by 'Ross Clark' is matched but the message with the number: +91 00580 00000 doesn't match. However, there also some rare cases when some messages with the number match.

Please help, I am new to this.

EDIT: I want to know when the sender is a name or a number, i.e I want the name to be catched by one group and number by another, so I can differentiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the format of the message and its like:

```
 <Date>, <Time> - ‪<NameOrNumber>‬: <Message>
```

Then you can search for the text in between the `-` and the `:`

1. Search with strings functions
2. Regex

## Version 1

Regex version based on your solution
`\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d,\s\d{1,2}:\d\d(\s\w\w)\s-\s(.+?): ((.*)(\n)*(.*))+` In this case 2nd group will have the name or the phonenumber
note the the forward slashed for `date` is escaped in this version so you may need to change it

## Version 2

`:.+?-\s(.+?):` search for a text in between the `-` and the `:` the first group will hold the `name` or the `phonenumber`. Assuming the `message format` mentioned above.

## Version 2+

`:[^-]+-\s([^:]+):` search for a text in between the `-` and the `:` the first group will hold the `name` or the `phonenumber`. Assuming the `message format` mentioned above.

## Version 3

`:.+?-\s(.+?):(.+)`
`first group` -  NameOrNumber
`2nd group` - Message

## Version 3+

`:[^-]+-\s([^:]+):(.+)`
`first group` -  NameOrNumber
`2nd group` - Message

## Version 4, Assuming Number starts with `+` and name does not

`:[^-]+-\s([^:\+]*)(\+*[^:]+):(.+)`

- First group holds the `name` if any
- 2nd group holds the `number` starts with `+` if any
- 3rd group holds the `message`
- [online version 4 example](https://regex101.com/r/lE1jC7/1)

## Version 5 - multi line support for message (date based delimiter)

`(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}),\s([^-]+)+-\s([^:\+]*)(\+*[^:]+):((.|\n(?!\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2},[^-]+))+)`

- First group holds the day
- 2nd group holds the time
- 3rd group holds the `name` if any
- 4th group holds the `number` starts with `+` if any
- 5th group holds the `message`
- 6th group holds the char after the delimiter
  [online version 5 example](https://regex101.com/r/uX3mZ1/4)

## How does version 5 work?

1. `(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})` look for `dd\mm\yy` format
2. `,\s([^-]+)+-\s` look for the time that should be after `,` and before  `-`
3. `([^:\+]*)(\+*[^:]+):` look for text before the next `:`. If there is `+` then its a number if there is non than its a name
4. `((.|\n(?!\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2},[^-]+))+)` - The tricky part. This is tricky because `.` find any char expect `new line`. So what does this part do? It search for any character or `\n` that is *not* followed by `dd\mm\yy,<anything here> -`. In simple word if `new line` start with date it does not capture it as part of the message.

## notes

`\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}` allows illegal dates like `99/99/99`. Its possible to prevent it but `its solution` is a verrrrrrry large `regex`

`,\s([^-]+)+-\s` - This search for the hour assuming its in between `,` and `-`. This can be done more carefully depending on the real needs.

Comment: I want to know when the sender is a name or a number, i.e I want the name to be catched by one group and number by another, so I can differentiate.

Comment: Hey @drishit96, can you assume the `number` starts with `+` and name does not start with `+`?

Comment: Yes @oak, I don't have any problem with your assumption.

Comment: I have a new problem. The messages can also have new lines, so I tried using ([\s\S]*) intead of (.+) to match the new lines as well. But, ([\s\S]*) is not stopping at the end of the first message and matches all the messages after it. The example: https://regex101.com/r/uX3mZ1/1. Any help?

Comment: The question is can we follow our `format`? How can we tell if this is new line in the `message` or this is `line` `new message`. For example imagine someone sending in his `message` the same `text` as the `metadata` i.e `02/05/16, 12:06 AM - ‪Ross Clark‬: Hello there! 02/05/16, \n\r 12:06 AM - ‪I'm still in the message I just want to tell the dates of something`. The question I'm is `What can be use in order to distinguish between new line in message (no matter what its content) and between `new line in log`

Comment: Can the date of the next message be used as a limiter? (not considering your case of embeded metadata, which is very rare).

Comment: Thanks a lot @oak, version 5 is working perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Lets use regex101 for this: https://regex101.com/r/qX0pQ2/1

The pattern I've used is:

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}),\s(\d{1,2}:\d{2}(?:\s(?:AM|PM)))?\s-\s(.*):\s(.*)
```

What does it mean? Regex101 explains it in detail but let me briefly highlight the changes. Simply put, use `.*` for the name and the message. It stands for "*any character, zero to arbitrary many*". You may change this to `.+` to ensure names or messages cannot be empty, if that is the case.

I abbreviated your `\d\d` stuff with `\d{2}`, which is the same. Also, as `/` is a character with a special meaning in regex; you need to escape it by adding a `\` in front of it if you just want to match the character itself. In Java, this escape-character itself has a special meaning (namely escaping things in Java-Strings). Thus you need to escape the escape-character in Java. Which leads to, for example, `\\/`.

But how can we implement this in Java itself? Here's some code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}),\\s(\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}(?:\\s(?:AM|PM)))?\\s-\\s(.*):\\s(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(inputText);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String date = matcher.group(1);
    String time = matcher.group(2);
    String name = matcher.group(3);
    String message = matcher.group(4);
    // Do something with this
}
```

There's one more thing: `(...)` is a capturing group. You can access the matched content using `matcher.group(X)`. If you want to use `(...)` without using a capturing group, you can use `(?:...)`, as I did for the AM, PM stuff.

Hope you understood everything, have fun. Here is the Pattern Documentation: [Pattern.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: `(.*):` should be `([^:]*):` to stop at the *first* colon. Slower version would be `(.*?):`.

Comment: Good point! Will be hard to match names that can have `:` in them. To be exact, the delimiter is `:\s`.

Answer (score 0):

This separates all major components into separate capturing groups:

`(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}),\s(\d{2}:\d{2}\s(?:AM|PM))\s-\s(.*):\s(.*)`

**Group 1**: MM/DD/YY

**Group 2**: HH:MM AM/PM

**Group 3**: Name or Number of sender

**Group 4**: Contents of the message

Comment: Group 3 matches `(AM|PM)` in your example. You may change it to `(?:AM|PM)` for not being a capturing group.